# Error on uploading files with Carrier Wave

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had `CarrierWave` working fine, until I had to change a field name on my table (the field which `CarrierWave` was mounted into) and now when I try to upload a file I get:

```
**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PhotosController#create** 
**TypeError: can't cast ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile to string: INSERT INTO "photos" ("album_id", "created_at", "rel", "road", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)**
```

My code:

**Photo.rb**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :album

    attr_accessible :legend, :road, :rel

    mount_uploader :road, UpperUploader 
end
```

**The uploader**

```
class UpperUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
     "../app/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.album_id}"
end
```

**The create action on PhotosController**

```
 def new
    @photo = Photo.new
 end

def create
    params[:photo][:road].each do |p|
      photo = Photo.new
      photo.road = p
      photo.rel = p
      photo.album_id = session[:current_album]
      photo.save
    end

    render 'manage'
end

def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:legend, :road, :album_id, :rel)
end
```

**My _form partial used to upload the files:**

```
<%= form_for @photo , html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <% if @photo.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@photo.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this photo from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @photo.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :road %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :road, :multiple => 'multiple' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

I changed the upload column name (what was 'path' to 'road') via migration, and, of course, I tried to change all the 'path' names on my code to 'road' . I tried to close and open the server several times, and the error persist.

Any help?

PS: The

> photo.rel = p

line is causing the error. If I comment it, all work fine. But why this line is causing this problem? And yes, I want a "rel" field that is a exactly copy of the "road" field, but that is not "mounted" ( and watched ) by CarrierWave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you are mounting the uploader to `road` column. As you specify with the following code:

`mount_uploader :road, UpperUploader`

However, when you try to assign it to `rel`, it raised an error `TypeError (can't cast ActionDispatch ...`, because `rel` is not the column that the uploader should be mounted to.

You can learn more about this in [CarrierWave Documentation](http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/Mount.html)